# Getting Bad request while searching run in mlflow

Tags: python, azure, azure-machine-learning-service, mlflow

Training a ml model with mlflow in azure environment.

```
import mlflow
from mlflow import MlflowClient
from azureml.core import Experiment, Workspace

experiment_name = 'housing-lin-mlflow'

experiment = Experiment(ws, experiment_name)

runs = mlflow.search_runs(experiment_ids=[ experiment.id ])
```

While fetching runs from search_runs getting this error :

```
RestException: BAD_REQUEST: For input string: "5b649b3c-3b8f-497a-bb4f"
```

MLflow version : 1.28.0
In Azure studio jobs have been created and successfully run.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The bad request in MLFlow after successful running the job is because of not giving proper API permissions for the application.

[image]

Search for **MLFLOW**

[image]

**Scroll down**

[image]

Click on View API Permissions

[image]

Under API permissions, assign the permissions according to the application running region and requirements. Checkout the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/how-to-manage-models-mlflow) for further information.